# Limit updates to once a week (or so)

Tags: updates

I get update notices as they come in (see screenshot)
I would like to limit them to, say, once a week but I don't see any options to do this.
How can I do this?

[image]

Based on comment from user5357533, I think this is the place:

[image: Updates]

Actually that doesn't appear to work. I just got an update notice

[image]

Comment: The setting is not in Discover. It's in Software & Updates. The default setting is for security updates to be installed automatically, immediately (twice daily) and without any notification. So you are really just changing the notification of less-critical non-security bugfixes.

Comment: Looks like you found it. Feel free to offer an answer to your own Question. It's preferable to munging the Question and Answer together above.

Comment: I can do that, but I thought you would like to get credit for the answer.